# Dockerのpushができない

Tags: docker

Docker Hub上のリボジトリーに、サーバーからdockerコマンドでコンテナイメージを
送信しようとすると、下記のように表示されて送信できない状態です。
解決方法を教えてください。
Docker Hubにログイン後に下記コマンドを実行しています。

```
[root@localhost ~]# docker login

Username (norio): norio
fiWARNING: login credentials saved in /root/.docker/config.json
Login Succeeded

[root@localhost ~]# docker push norio/httpd

Do you really want to push to public registry? [y/n]: y
The push refers to a repository [docker.io/norio/httpd] (len: 0)
e65d30dccd47: Preparing 
**unauthorized: authentication required**
```

環境はVMWare上にCentOS7を立てています。

Dockerのversionは以下となります。

Client:
 Version:         1.9.1
 API version:     1.21
 Package version: docker-1.9.1-25.el7.centos.x86_64
 Go version:      go1.4.2
 Git commit:      78ee77d/1.9.1
 Built:           
 OS/Arch:         linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:         1.9.1
 API version:     1.21
 Package version: docker-1.9.1-25.el7.centos.x86_64
 Go version:      go1.4.2
 Git commit:      78ee77d/1.9.1
 Built:           
 OS/Arch:         linux/amd64

Comment: 手元(ubuntu)だと再現しないですね…

Comment: 質問には書かれていないようですが、Usernameの後にPasswordとEmailの入力は求められていますか？また、config.jsonに記録されている資格情報を改変してみると同様のエラーになったので、正しく記録されているか確認してみてください。config.jsonのauthに書かれている文字列は単にBASE64エンコードされているだけなので、デコードすれば平文に戻せます。とりあえずCentOS7+docker1.10.3では問題ありませんでした。

Comment: PasswordとEmailの入力は求められています。
authをデコードした結果は、想定通りのユーザーIDとパスワードでした。

Comment: 同じバージョンを入れてみましたがやはり問題なくpushできました。WARNINGの前についている `fi` が気になりますが、ググってもそれらしい情報はないですねえ・・・。別の環境からpushしてみるとか、色々試してみるしかないように思います。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

自己解決しました。
SELinuxを無効にしたらpushできました。

Answer (score 0):

https://askubuntu.com/a/688875/448557 が参考になるかもしれないです。

```
docker login
```

を、docker ホスト上でまず最初に(`docker push`の前に)実行する必要がありますが、これは実行されましたか？

Comment: docker loginは実施済みです。ログイン部分も質問のところに載せておきました。
fiWARNINGというのが原因かもしれないです。